# Can't start Synergy server service

Tags: synergy

everytime I try to start the Synergy Server service (out of services) I get an error code 4. 
I tried to install .Net Framework 4 but it didn't help.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Not really a fix, but an alternative... I switched from Synergy to "Mouse Without Borders" http://blogs.technet.com/b/next/archive/2011/09/09/microsoft-garage-download-mouse-without-borders.aspx

But of course, that only works if you are on windows only, what are the OS's?

Comment: I use 'service start synergy' in my startup - It doesn't start natively

Comment: @lysdexic it's a great app!

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://synergy-foss.org/pm/issues/1869) contains two suggestions for the problem. You may try them:

> 1. I had the same problem with Windows 2003 Server x64. I found a workaround
>      however - I copied the synergy.sgc
>      file from the current user's "My
>      Documents" to the Default User's "My
>      Documents" directory. Once I did this
>      the service started up fine.
> 2. error 4 does mean the configuration couldn't be read. try running
>      synergy.exe and click "Configure"
>      under "Automatic Startup". turn off
>      autostart when the computer starts
>      then turn it back on again. then quit
>      and try manually starting the service.